# Which metals hydroxides dissolve in excess NH4OH?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reference-request

Some metal hydroxides like $\ce{Ag(OH)}$ and $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$ dissolve in excess $\ce{NH4OH}$ to form metal ammonia complexes.

I want to know which other common metal hydroxides dissolve in excess $\ce{NH4OH}$. Also, can it be somehow predicted ? I couldn't find much relevant information on the Internet.

Comment: There are a number of unknowns and a number of equations but this is a matter of the various equilibriums. Remember that you could also add NaOH so the solution could be more basic than you could get with NH4OH alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_ammine_complex) for "Metal amine complex" gives many examples.  According to the article:

> Almost all metal ions bind ammonia as a ligand, but the most prevalent
>   examples of ammine complexes are for Cr(III), Co(III), Ni(II), Cu(II)
>   as well as several platinum group metals.

Specific examples include:

$\ce{[Pt(NH3)4][PtCl4]}$
$\ce{[RhCl(NH3)5]Cl2}$
$\ce{[Cr(NH3)4Cl2]Cl}$
$\ce{[Co(NH3)6]Cl3}$
$\ce{NH4[Cr(NCS)4(NH3)2]}$
$\ce{[Zn(NH3)4]^2+}$
$\ce{[Ag(NH3)2]+}$
$\ce{[Ni(NH3)6]^2+}$
$\ce{[Cu(NH3)4(H2O)2]^2+}$

Several others are listed just in that one Wikipedia article, along with a fair list of references.