# Which metal ions precipitate in NH4OH?

Tags: solubility, metal, amines, precipitation

From [Wikipedia-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_ammine_complex), and from an answer here on [Stack-Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/68139/which-metals-hydroxides-dissolve-in-excess-nh4oh), I can list at least the following elements which will dissolve in aqueous $\ce{NH4OH}$:

- $\ce{Cr(III), Co(III), Ni(II), Cu(I, II), Zn(II), Ag(I),}$ along with  "several platinum group metals"

From reading [Wikipedia-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonia#Liquid_ammonia_as_a_solvent), I also suspect the following elements to dissolve in liquid ammonia:

- $\ce{Mg, Ca, Sr, Ba, Eu, Yb, Li, Na, K}$ and $\ce{Rb}$

As a matter of fact, according to Wikipedia "almost all metal ions bind ammonia as a ligand." I thought it would be interesting, and potentially very useful, to find out which metal ions are NOT soluble in $\ce{NH4OH}$.

I can list two for now:

- $\ce{Fe(OH)3}$
- $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$ with a solubility product of only $5.61×10^{−12}$ (credit to Oscar Lanzi)

Comment: There is a huge difference in pure liquid $\ce{NH3}$  and an aqueous solution of $\ce{NH4OH}$. I can't imagine any of the metals Mg, Ca, Sr, Ba, Li, Na, K or Rb forming amine complexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case of magnesium ion, at least, it seems a stretch to say it dissolves in ammonia solution.  Assume that the ammonia solution has $\mathrm{pH}$ of $11$ and magnesium hydroxide has a solubility product of [$5.61×10^{-12}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium_hydroxide). We infer that the magnesium ion solubility at equilibrium with the hydroxide in ammonia solution is only $\pu{5.6μM}$ which is not really all that soluble.

Magnesium ion is appreciably soluble not in an ammonia solution but in a *buffered* solution of ammonia and an ammonium salt.